# What is happening to my lists?

Tags: python, list, class

I have class Dot

```
class Dot:   
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x=x
    self.y=y
```

I have class Cluster

```
class Cluster:
    ic=0
    List=[Dot]
    colour=0
    def __init__(self, Dot):
      self.List[self.ic]=Dot 
      self.ic=self.ic+1
    def includeDot(self, Dot):
      self.List[self.ic]=Dot 
      self.ic=self.ic+1
```

Which include list of dots(List).

And I have class ClusterMaker where is list of clusters(and some other procedures, but this is not important for this question)

```
class ClusterMaker:
    total=0
    i=0
    CList=[Cluster]  
    def addCluster(self,Cluster):
         self.CList.append(Cluster)
```

Finally, there is button on my form which starts creating dots and clusters

```
def onChoose(self):            
       # ClMaker=ClusterMaker()   
       self.total=self.ent.get().strip() #how many dots we haver
       self.CM=ClusterMaker()
       i=0    
       while (i < int(self.total)):
          dot=Dot(randint(0, 575), randint(0,670))
          clst=Cluster(dot)
          clst.colour= randrange(100, 999, 15)  
          self.CM.addCluster(clst)
          box.showerror('j', str(str(self.CM.CList[i].List[0].x)+str(clst.List[0].x)))
          this box shows us x coord of every dot in our cluster list
          self.canvas.create_oval(clst.List[0].x, clst.List[0].y, clst.List[0].x+10, clst.List[0].y+10, fill=str("#"+str(clst.colour)))
          i=i+1 
       b=0
       while(b<6):
          box.showerror('j', str(self.CM.CList[b].List[0].x))
          and this box shows us x coords too
          b=b+1
```

But what is going on in my lists? Why when I ask to show x coords for the second time it show the same x coord for all dots in all clusters?

Comment: `ic` (in your class), and `self.ic` are not the same thing, and please don't name your variable `List`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class attributes are instantiated once and shared between instances.  You have to create fresh list in `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, Dot):
    self.List = [Dot]
    self.List[self.ic]=Dot 
    self.ic=self.ic+1
```

Comment: thanks, i wish i could vote you up) when i'll have more reputation I will. I have only 11 and need 15